# Convert Whatsapp markdown to HTML tags

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to convert Whatsapp markdown to HTML tags.

Eg.

```
*Bold* to <b>Bold</b>
_Italic_ to <i>Italic</i>
```

I want to use regex to capture the words in the string.

Here is the link, containing the test case, and my best shot at it.
https://regexr.com/4gnqr

The regex should capture both `*bold*` and `*some more bold text*`.

Comment: Check the `global` flag at the right top.

Comment: I don't know what the difference between the markdown used in Whatsapp and for example Github is? For parsing markdown to html you can use a library to avoid edge cases. [ShowDown](https://github.com/showdownjs/showdown) is a known one.

Comment: @Thefourthbird Thanks, wanted to try it but wasn't able to type it into the input box. Didn't notice that Flags section at the top right.

Comment: @iepur1lla Thanks, but didn't want to download a library for such a small use case.

Comment: Make sure you know the [limitations](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/735964) of parsing a Chomsky type 2 grammar with a Chomsky type 3 grammar.

Comment: Can you show the regex you've used and the target used on ? What about `_*sadf*_` ?

Comment: I think they use the standard markdown syntax so this will work https://github.com/markdown-it/markdown-it

Comment: One more note. If you decide to go with custom regex solution remember this is how xss happens in applications, so make sure you protect yourself against it.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use these two expressions,

```
(\*)([^*]+?)(\*)
```

---

```
(_)([^_]+?)(_)
```

and replace it with:

```
<b>$2</b>
```

---

```
<i>$2</i>
```

and that might solve the problem.

#### [Demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/2j3PUZ/1/)

#### [Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/7lob6L/1/)

#### Example

```js
const regex = /(_)([^_]+?)(_)/gs;
const str = `*Bold* to <b>Bold</b>
_Italic_ to <i>Italic</i>
This is a *bold* text, along with *some more bold text*. We also have some _italic_ text.`;
const subst = `<i>$2</i>`;
const result = str.replace(regex, subst);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: You shouldn't use a backteference to a known value. Also, capturing the known value is useless. Also, discern the regexes as different and separate.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a simple regex:

```js
const regex = /\*(.*?)\*/g;
const test = "*bold*, not bold, *bold again*";
//            ^1   ^2           ^3         ^4
const result = test.replace(regex , '<strong>$1</strong>')
console.log(result)
```

- You want from `*` to the next `*` and save everything in between: `*(.*?)*`
  (without the `?` it would go from first to last <sup>(eg 1->4 instead of 1->2, 3->4)</sup>, it's called (non)greedy).
- That doesn't work because `*` is a regex character, so you must escape -> `\*`.
- The `/g` means 'global', e.g. replace all occurences (as opposed to only the first).
- `$1` holds our first (and in this case only) value.

The underscore version works the same, and doesn't need escaping like `*` does.

Answer (score 0):

Choose the  perfect regex that will fit your needs.
If you don't want styling to span through new line and also using `([^*<\n]+)` makes sure at least one character is in between styles or else `**` without a character in-between will become invisible.

````
function format_text(text){
return text.replace(/(?:\*)([^*<\n]+)(?:\*)/g, "<strong>$1</strong>")
     .replace(/(?:_)([^_<\n]+)(?:_)/g, "<i>$1</i>")
      .replace(/(?:~)([^~<\n]+)(?:~)/g, "<s>$1</s>")
      .replace(/(?:```)([^```<\n]+)(?:```)/g, "<tt>$1</tt>")
}
````

•The downside to the above code is that, you can't nest styles i.e  `*_Bold and italic_*`

To allow nested styles use this

````
format_text(text){
return text.replace(/(?:\*)(?:(?!\s))((?:(?!\*|\n).)+)(?:\*)/g,'<b>$1</b>')
   .replace(/(?:_)(?:(?!\s))((?:(?!\n|_).)+)(?:_)/g,'<i>$1</i>')
   .replace(/(?:~)(?:(?!\s))((?:(?!\n|~).)+)(?:~)/g,'<s>$1</s>')
   .replace(/(?:--)(?:(?!\s))((?:(?!\n|--).)+)(?:--)/g,'<u>$1</u>')
   .replace(/(?:```)(?:(?!\s))((?:(?!\n|```).)+)(?:```)/g,'<tt>$1</tt>');

// extra:
// --For underlined text--
// ```Monospace font```
}
````

If you want your style to span through new line, then remove `\n`  from the regex. Also if your new line is html break tag, you can replace `\n` with `<br>`