# How convert whatsapp formatted in ruby?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a formated text in **ruby** with `*text in bold*` and `_ text in italic_`
How to replace all `*text in bold*` by `<b> text in bold </b>`
and `_ text in italic _` by `<i> text in italic </i>` ?

Comment: https://github.com/vmg/redcarpet - Check out this gem for converting markdown into HTML.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried but redcarpet change `*bold*` to italic instead of bold

Comment: It seems the markdown syntax for Whatsapp is different, Please check out this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56839082/convert-whatsapp-markdown-to-html-tags

Comment: Thanks. You saved my day. I used regex. Your link helped.

Comment: Glad that helped